# Task is to calculate the straight line distance between the two objects moving in a circle

Tags: c

[image]

We have two point objects B and C at rest on a straight line at a distance r1 and r2 units from a point A. At time t=0 seconds, the objects start moving in a circular path with A at the center with angular velocity v1 and v2 degrees per second.

Given inputs v1, v2, r1 and r2, calculate the distance between the B and C after N seconds.
I've done it but it's giving the wrong answer can anyone suggest me a better solution.

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"math.h"
int main()
{
    float v1,v2,r1,r2,t;
    scanf("%f%f%f%f%f", &v1, &r1, &v2, &r2, &t);

    int diff = v1 > v2 ? (v1 - v2) : (v2 - v1);
    int total_diff = diff * t;

    if(total_diff % 360 == 0)
        printf("%.2f", r2 - r1);
    else if(total_diff % 180 == 0)
        printf("%.2f", r1 + r2);
    else if(total_diff % 90 == 0)
        printf("%.2f", sqrt(pow(r2, 2) - pow(r1, 2)));
    else
        printf("%.2f", sqrt(pow(total_diff, 2) - pow(r2-r1, 2)));
}
```

I've taken else part from:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727504/calculate-distance-between-two-points-on-concentric-circles

Comment: It appears you are always taking the x coordinate of each point to be the radius its the circle. You need to take the actual x value, which would be less than or equal to the radius.

Comment: `v1-v2` and `v2-v1` are floats; why are you storing them in an `int`?

Comment: An other option would be to calculate the difference of angular velocities gamma=v1/r1-v2/r2. Then, at time t, the angle between AB-AC would be gamma*t. Finally, the distance between the planets could be computed by appling the Law of cosines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines .

Comment: Please learn to space tokens properly. I have edited your code; I hope you see the difference and learn proper indentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Better method as requested**

I would use polar coordinates for this. It fits the problem much better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float distance(float v1, float r1, float v2, float r2, float dt) {
    // Calculate new positions and convert to radians                           
    float fi1 = v1*dt*M_PI/180, fi2 = v2*dt*M_PI/180;
    // Polar distance formula                                                   
    return sqrt(pow(r1, 2) + pow(r2, 2) - 2*r1*r2*cos(fi1-fi2));
}

int main()
{
    float v1,v2,r1,r2,t;
    scanf("%f%f%f%f%f",&v1,&r1,&v2,&r2,&t);
    printf("%.2f\n", distance(v1,r1,v2,r2,t));
}
```